# Paypal sandbox verify webhook always return FAILURE

Tags: go, paypal, verify

I was run it in golang, sandbox, not use the webhooks simulator, and use http.NewRequest POST `/v1/notifications/verify-webhook-signature` to verify

header are already use access_token

```
var verifyData struct {
        AuthAlgo         string                 `json:"auth_algo"`
        CertUrl          string                 `json:"cert_url"`
        TransmissionId   string                 `json:"transmission_id"`
        TransmissionSig  string                 `json:"transmission_sig"`
        TransmissionTime string                 `json:"transmission_time"`
        WebhookEvent     map[string]interface{} `json:"webhook_event"`
        WebhookId        string                 `json:"webhook_id"`
    }
```

but it always return `{"verification_status":"FAILURE"}`, all webhook verify are the same

i try to Println logs

but the `WebhookEvent` are the same as webhook `http.Body()` data

other data are the same as webhook `http.Header` data

data from webhook header

```
Paypal-Auth-Algo:SHA256withRSA 
Paypal-Cert-Url:https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/certs/CERT-360caa42-fca2a594-******** 
Paypal-Transmission-Id:422dea50-c3ac-****-****-b9f65296f9e3 
Paypal-Transmission-Sig:Col8aQ2wP+qVt6Xe8XBXwWX6ANyFVlEfdTCgScqRD3mbCYZb0p5yh5uWNLQ8sPAbIXByuOrYs7+******+Ty+5UpFyj+x3CTTXlQgyAmWdiETlfE93tpjVY1OZhLDYDrdUVdF9PIT1snS0pmRX17vVcxN9GooqFd7BeZCJoPo83MWxV2V+0wcpGtxG2V5tw17xTF9XLiTIAsnNVZw/*********/NMvopi3P7EJUWteqtxrow/fmf27uUhTmLtF9sNFcOP2nBKIPDo0Wearf78P1Yr2gLDxfis3s8d/qNWqSs75Mk7wOm/YQrj2R74jikQFU46v3UD5tYrwIBh77Hg== 
Paypal-Transmission-Time:2023-03-16T03:40:13Z
```

and `webhook_event` are from `http.Body()`, it's use `json.Unmarshal` to `map[string]interface{}`

`webhook_id` from apps,SANDBOX WEBHOOKS

i try any ways to change webhook_event, still not work

i don't know how to use `<transmissionId>|<timeStamp>|<webhookId>|<crc32>` in golang, so i use http.post now, please help

Comment: In your question, include (1) a log of the complete webhook body received (and the headers, which you included already), and (2) an example of your resulting verifyData body right before you post it back to the API. Show all values in their entirety, it's sandbox.  You can even include the sandbox clientid+secret so it can be tested with curl/postman

Comment: A couple notes are that: yes webhookId must come from the correct app in https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/applications/sandbox -> Sandbox Webhooks. It will be 17 alphanumeric capitals.

Comment: For your verify request, everything needs to have right key in the resulting JSON object. See https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/webhooks/v1/#verify-webhook-signature_post for an example request. If anything is named incorrectly or if the webhook_event contents are not precisely what you received, it will fail.

Comment: The webhook_evevnt i was use all the same data, and webhook_id i was copy in sandbox, it's 17 alphanumeric capitals, others data are from webhook header copy too

Answer (score 1):

my example from sandbox

--webhook request headers--

```
map[
    Accept:*/* Content-Length:1142
    Content-Type:application/json
    Correlation-Id:f941618bd2165
    Host:filepipe.dev
    Paypal-Auth-Algo:SHA256withRSA
    Paypal-Auth-Version:v2
    Paypal-Cert-Url:https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/certs/CERT-360caa42-fca2a594-5a29e601
    Paypal-Transmission-Id:99d97fc0-c3ad-11ed-8ada-d722609ae478
    Paypal-Transmission-Sig:PrZDo9fmpTshwt/JY6/HvJDceR5kCj3GhAxdiBSIdtsC7Y91+ww6hd8Qk5zpnJ3KN1itLYSxFnTQLOgtOYZtSzXsQaAeo7oSqxUAaV+jXtF3a63zR0zg9NRHfNjf4L7JuGJ0WDz2I4d4026GZ4yXjr3sNc3zN6dEwZBEQT0zc+bwZjariIC3WQv7uLCPKbvl6g49OhQC6xS5cJkB837D3svUIlT/9PEJ5mp1WCCijwOypUpCoP1lXGWHx1pVvtTPd4Q3ANSSASFJDs4ubJKgH5CPNiv+eT9GNs5JGXQv/1qlvCN+Ph2v/OKgz6yM5gbPS3XnldccXwnzeGcenPvl5w==
    Paypal-Transmission-Time:2023-03-16T03:49:49Z
    User-Agent:PayPal/AUHR-214.0-58031014
    X-B3-Spanid:3d19edb457d98398
    X-Forwarded-For:173.0.80.116
    X-Forwarded-Host:filepipe.dev
    X-Forwarded-Port:443
    X-Forwarded-Proto:https
    X-Forwarded-Scheme:https
    X-Real-Ip:173.0.80.116
    X-Request-Id:fd024917ba5320920ea36735f2460a47
    X-Scheme:https
]
```

--webhook body json--

```
{
    "id": "WH-47139463N7609432M-6FD472938E900521U",
    "event_version": "1.0",
    "create_time": "2023-03-16T03:49:46.098Z",
    "resource_type": "subscription",
    "resource_version": "2.0",
    "event_type": "BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.CREATED",
    "summary": "Subscription created",
    "resource": {
        "start_time": "2023-03-16T03:49:45Z",
        "quantity": "1",
        "create_time": "2023-03-16T03:49:45Z",
        "custom_id": "3",
        "links": [
            {
                "href": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/billing/subscriptions?ba_token=BA-7RE73133KF159744D",
                "rel": "approve",
                "method": "GET"
            },
            {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-LMA62KG79TL5",
                "rel": "edit",
                "method": "PATCH"
            },
            {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-LMA62KG79TL5",
                "rel": "self",
                "method": "GET"
            }
        ],
        "id": "I-LMA62KG79TL5",
        "plan_overridden": false,
        "plan_id": "P-2M355934NH158234GMQIXO2Q",
        "status": "APPROVAL_PENDING"
    },
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/WH-47139463N7609432M-6FD472938E900521U",
            "rel": "self",
            "method": "GET"
        },
        {
            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/WH-47139463N7609432M-6FD472938E900521U/resend",
            "rel": "resend",
            "method": "POST"
        }
    ]
}
```

--webhook body interface{}--

```
map[
    create_time:2023-03-16T03:49:46.098Z 
    event_type:BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.CREATED 
    event_version:1.0 
    id:WH-47139463N7609432M-6FD472938E900521U 
    links:[
        map[
            href:https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/WH-47139463N7609432M-6FD472938E900521U 
            method:GET 
            rel:self
        ] 
        map[
            href:https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/WH-47139463N7609432M-6FD472938E900521U/resend 
            method:POST 
            rel:resend
        ]
    ] 
    resource:
        map[
            create_time:2023-03-16T03:49:45Z 
            custom_id:3 
            id:I-LMA62KG79TL5 
            links:[
                map[
                    href:https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/billing/subscriptions?ba_token=BA-7RE73133KF159744D 
                    method:GET 
                    rel:approve
                ] 
                map[
                    href:https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-LMA62KG79TL5 
                    method:PATCH 
                    rel:edit
                ] 
                map[
                    href:https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-LMA62KG79TL5 
                    method:GET 
                    rel:self
                ]
            ] 
            plan_id:P-2M355934NH158234GMQIXO2Q 
            plan_overridden:false 
            quantity:1 
            start_time:2023-03-16T03:49:45Z 
            status:APPROVAL_PENDING
        ] 
    resource_type:subscription 
    resource_version:2.0 
    summary:Subscription created
]
```

--send verify data--

```
{
    "auth_algo": "SHA256withRSA",
    "cert_url": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/certs/CERT-360caa42-fca2a594-5a29e601",
    "transmission_id": "99d97fc0-c3ad-11ed-8ada-d722609ae478",
    "transmission_sig": "PrZDo9fmpTshwt/JY6/HvJDceR5kCj3GhAxdiBSIdtsC7Y91+ww6hd8Qk5zpnJ3KN1itLYSxFnTQLOgtOYZtSzXsQaAeo7oSqxUAaV+jXtF3a63zR0zg9NRHfNjf4L7JuGJ0WDz2I4d4026GZ4yXjr3sNc3zN6dEwZBEQT0zc+bwZjariIC3WQv7uLCPKbvl6g49OhQC6xS5cJkB837D3svUIlT/9PEJ5mp1WCCijwOypUpCoP1lXGWHx1pVvtTPd4Q3ANSSASFJDs4ubJKgH5CPNiv+eT9GNs5JGXQv/1qlvCN+Ph2v/OKgz6yM5gbPS3XnldccXwnzeGcenPvl5w==",
    "transmission_time": "2023-03-16T03:49:49Z",
    "webhook_event": {
        "create_time": "2023-03-16T03:49:46.098Z",
        "event_type": "BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.CREATED",
        "event_version": "1.0",
        "id": "WH-47139463N7609432M-6FD472938E900521U",
        "links": [
            {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/WH-47139463N7609432M-6FD472938E900521U",
                "method": "GET",
                "rel": "self"
            },
            {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/WH-47139463N7609432M-6FD472938E900521U/resend",
                "method": "POST",
                "rel": "resend"
            }
        ],
        "resource": {
            "create_time": "2023-03-16T03:49:45Z",
            "custom_id": "3",
            "id": "I-LMA62KG79TL5",
            "links": [
                {
                    "href": "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/billing/subscriptions?ba_token=BA-7RE73133KF159744D",
                    "method": "GET",
                    "rel": "approve"
                },
                {
                    "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-LMA62KG79TL5",
                    "method": "PATCH",
                    "rel": "edit"
                },
                {
                    "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-LMA62KG79TL5",
                    "method": "GET",
                    "rel": "self"
                }
            ],
            "plan_id": "P-2M355934NH158234GMQIXO2Q",
            "plan_overridden": false,
            "quantity": "1",
            "start_time": "2023-03-16T03:49:45Z",
            "status": "APPROVAL_PENDING"
        },
        "resource_type": "subscription",
        "resource_version": "2.0",
        "summary": "Subscription created"
    },
    "webhook_id": "9FU18601MK8788***" (webhook id)
}
```

--verify data--

```
{"verification_status":"FAILURE"}
```

i was use `Paypal-Auth-Algo` `Paypal-Cert-Url` `Paypal-Transmission-Id` `Paypal-Transmission-Sig` `Paypal-Transmission-Time` from header, and all `webhook body interface{}`, and the webhook_id from apps/webhook

Comment: At a glance the only thing I can think of is that the webhook_event key's contents are not exactly as what you received in the webhook body (different order after JSON parsing). I don't know if this matters, would need sandbox credentials and actual sandbox webhookid to test with curl/postman and see what else may be off, or try that yourself.

Comment: oh! i try to test it in postman, and as you say, it's a question of different order, when i copy the origin json to event, it send me `SUCCESS`